# Как скопировать определенный текст в буфер обмена по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: android

Как скопировать определенный текст в буфер обмена по нажатию на кнопку?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Делается так:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", editText.getText().toString());
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void copyText(String copiedText) {
    int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setText(copiedText);
    } else {
        android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("TAG",copiedText);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
}
```

По нажатию на кнопку передавайте нужный текст в этот метод. Это если фрагмент.
Если нет, то замените `getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);`

Answer (score 2):

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

После чего у вас появиться edit панель, где можно копировать выделенный текст.
Но если это не решит проблему, отпишите я добавлю ответ.